# can't get my recursion function to work with a list

Tags: haskell

Passing in a list such as: [1,2,3,4,5]
and get back [ [1,2,3,4,5] , [2,3,4,5] , [3,4,5] , [4,5] , [5] , [] ]

my approach is using recursion to add `drop 1 list` to another empty list until list is empty. but I can't seem to get my recursion to work correctly.

help please, thanks

my code so far:

```
test a = test2 a where
test2 a | size(a) > 1 = test (drop 1 a):[]
        | otherwise = []
```

but that wouldnt work because the recursion is passing back a list in a list, not a list. I just cant figure out how you can assign it to something and return it at the same time.

Comment: Where's the code? We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if we can't see what you did in the first place

Comment: I don't know haskell so I might be wrong but I think you need to check the case where you want to print the original list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, what did you do the  `test a = test2 a` for?

Then, you don't need (and shouldn't use) guards for this, do it with pattern matching:

```
test [] = [[]]
test (a:al) = (a:al):(test al)
```

If you insist on using guards, you still need do make it actually a list of lists:

```
test a
  | null a    = [[]]
  | otherwise = a:(test $ tail a)
```

(Not a list of lists *of lists*, as I had in my original post...)

Comment: I was trying another approach with a helper function, I guess in this case I don't need it. thanks!

Comment: That last line should be `a : (test (tail a))` - notice the input list `a` shouldn't be encapsulated as a new singleton list.

Answer (score 6):

The function you're describing is already in the standard library, where it's called [`Data.List.tails`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3atails). You can have a look at [its source code](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#tails) to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with your `drop 1` approach, you could write

```
test xs = take (1 + length xs) $ iterate (drop 1) xs
```

A slightly funny version is

```
import Data.List

test = (++[[]]) . transpose . zipWith replicate [1..]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fromNet [] = [[]]
fromNet lst =  lst : fromNet (tail lst)
```